# Dynamic variable key value pair array

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to dynamically assign an array? The code doesn't work as intended. It fails at `var p = { z }`

```
var z = "\"" + m[0] + "\"" + " : " + "\"" + (m[0] = m[1]) + "\"";

if(i != u.length - 1){
  z = z + ",";
}

var p = {z}

for (var key in p) {
  if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    client = Elements.AddNew(key, p[key]);
    client.Update();
  }
}
```

Entire code

```
var fso, f1, ts, s;
        var ForReading = 1;
        fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        // Read the contents of the file.
        Session.Output("Reading file");
        ts = fso.OpenTextFile("c:\\temp\\roles.txt", ForReading);
        s = ts.ReadAll();
        u = s.split('\r\n');
        Session.Output(u);
        for(i = 0; i < u.length; i++){
        m = u[i].split(",");
        var z = "\"" + m[0] + "\"" + " : " + "\"" + (m[0] = m[1]) + "\"";

            if(i != u.length - 1){
                z = z + ",";
            }

                    var p = {
                        z
                    }
                    Session.Output(p);

        for (var key in p) 
        {
            if (p.hasOwnProperty(key))
            {
            client = Elements.AddNew(key, p[key]);
            client.Update();
            }
        }   


        }
```

The contents of the file are as follows. It's a comma delimited file.

```
abc,1
def,2
ghi,3
```

Comment: Should `(m[0] = m[1])` be `(m[0] == m[1])`? It doesn't make sense to me to do an assignment here.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create an object like that.

You need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) as the [member operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators) to do this

```
var p = {}

p[m[0]] = m[1];


for (var key in p) {
    if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        client = Elements.AddNew(key, p[key]);
        client.Update();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but as soon as it hits ` client = Elements.AddNew(key, p[key]);`, it returns the message `invalid type`.

Comment: why not just use var p = JSON.parse(z)

Comment: @clancer when there is such a cleaner and right way to do it why do you want to complicate things

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey check the value assigned to the object and see whether it is matching with the expected behavior

Comment: @clancer - I can't use JSON as the script editor in use has limited support. It's part of a third-party tool.

Comment: @Arun P Johny - Sorry for being such a n00b. How would i do that?

Comment: look at [console logging](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console) and [javascript debugging](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging)

Comment: @Arun P Johny- No value is being assigned. All that is returned is `[object Object]`

Comment: which is the browser used? try `console.log(JSON.stringify(p))` just before the for loop

Comment: @Arun P Johny - As mentioned earlier to clancer, it is being run inside of an editor of a third-party application and i can't use JSON.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that:

```
(m[0] = m[1])
```

should have been:

```
(m[0] == m[1])
```

If you have an array *m* that is like:

```
var m = ['a', 'b', 'b'];
```

you seem to be trying to make an object using the pattern:

```
var z = { m[0] : (m[0] == m[1]) };
```

which can be written:

```
var z = {};
z[m[0]] = m[0] == m[1];
```

An object can be created from the array using:

```
var z = {};
for (var i=0, iLen=m.length - 1; i<iLen; i++) {
  z[m[i]] = m[i] == m[i+1];
}
```

Which will create an object like:

```
{a: false, b: true}
```

Comment: I have updated my post with the entire code to show what i am trying to achieve.